# Applescript - System events - Set default location for "open file" popup window

Tags: macos, applescript

Im using system events to control a program that does not have a applescript library. 
I am therefor using system events to control it.

I have gotten the program to open a pop up window for it Open File interface and I would like to get it to default to a certain location. Is this possible.
So Far I have :

```
tell application "App Name"
activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
tell process "App Name"
    tell menu bar 1
        tell menu bar item "File"
            tell menu "File"
                tell menu item "Import"
                    tell menu "Import"
                        click menu item "XML..."
                        delay 4

                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

The pop up window defaults to its own last visited location. I would like it to default to a given file path like /Users/userabc/Documents/abcd.XML

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the "posix path" of a location and the dialog box open, you can do the following. Note that the location can be a folder or a file path. If it's a file path then that file will be selected and you would then just have to "keystroke return" to close the dialog box and open that file. Good luck.

```
set theLocation to path to home folder
set posixLocation to POSIX path of theLocation

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
    delay 0.5
    keystroke posixLocation
    delay 0.5
    keystroke return
end tell
```

Comment: Nice, works a treat! Can I also prompt for a default filename as well as file path?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with this method is that autocorrect starts filling in as apple script types into the text box and screws everything up.  Work around is to copy/paste into from applescript.

Answer (score 0):

The keystroke command doesn't work for inserting characters that can't be inserted with the current input source. And it doesn't work at all with some input sources.

You could also set the value of the text field:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
    keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
    tell window 1
        tell sheet 1
            set value of text field 1 to "/usr/share/dict/connectives"
            click button 1
        end tell
        click button "Open"
    end tell
end tell
```